# Change css value on div depending on the SQL database value

Tags: php, html, css, sql

So im creating like an order status page that had 5 steps. All the backgrounds are red by default. I have a table in SQl that holds a number of 1-5 that is updated in a sql database. When the customer places there code in the page I set up , I want it to log onto the database checks to see which number is active in the sql database then overrides the cosponsoring div with a  green background .

```
  .SqlActive{
    background-color:green !important;
  }
```

I know what I want it too do but I have no clue on how to begin coding this. I know a little php and SQL.
go to webpage type in code.
based on code SQL grabs row and checks number in status column and overrides the css to green based on the number in SQl column 1-5.
So if 3 is the number in the status column the 3rd div would be green the rest would be red.
Can anyone point me in the right direction or a sample code to get me started? Do I have to learn ASP or ajax or similar?

```css
.service1{
z-index: 99; 
background-image: url(../images/);
border: 1px solid yellow;
background-color:#ff0000;
margin:10px;padding:10px;
height:200px;
width:95%;

}

.service2{margin:5px;padding:5px;   z-index: 99; 
background-image: url(../images/);
height:189px;   
width:90%;
border: 1px solid yellow;background-color:#ff0000;
margin:5px;
}

.service3{margin:5px;padding:5px;   
background-image: url(../images/);
height:189px;
width:90%;
border: 1px solid yellow;background-color:#ff0000;
margin:5px;
}

.service4{margin:5px;padding:5px;
    background-image: url(../images/);  
height:189px;
width:90%;
border: 1px solid yellow;background-color:#ff0000;
margin:5px; 
}

.service5{  margin:5px;padding:5px;
background-image: url(../images/);
height:189px;
width:90%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;background-color:#ff0000;
margin:5px;
}

.SqlActive{
    background-color:green !important;
}
```

```html
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM table' ;
$results = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("<br>Bad query: $sql");



<div class="service1">
<div class="Spic">pic</div><!---->
<div class="Shead">header</div><!---->
<div class="Scont">content</div><!---->
</div><!--service1-->
<div class="service2">
<div class="Spic">pic</div><!---->
<div class="Shead">header</div><!---->
<div class="Scont">content</div><!---->
</div><!--service2-->
<div class="service3">
<div class="Spic">pic</div><!---->
<div class="Shead">header</div><!---->
<div class="Scont">content</div><!---->
</div><!--service3-->
<div class="service4">
<div class="Spic">pic</div><!---->
<div class="Shead">header</div><!---->
<div class="Scont">content</div><!---->
</div><!--service4-->
<div class="service5">
<div class="Spic">pic</div><!---->
<div class="Shead">header</div><!---->
<div class="Scont">content</div><!---->
</div><!--service5-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start would be reading up on some PHP learning resources, quite a few on YouTube etc.

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b3p6 - if you go here, press "execute" and view the HTML tab you can see a "working" version of your code.

**PLEASE NOTE - IMPORTANT** - You'll need to read up on SQL injection to prevent people from hacking your application if you're allowing the user to enter data which is used as part of a MySQL query. Google mysqli prepared statements (or better yet, PDO, which is a nicer DB extension for PHP).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .service1{
                z-index: 99;
                background-image: url(../images/);
                border: 1px solid yellow;
                background-color:#ff0000;
                margin:10px;
                padding:10px;
                height:200px;
                width:95%;
            }
            .service2{
                margin:5px;
                padding:5px;
                z-index: 99;
                background-image: url(../images/);
                height:189px;
                width:90%;
                border: 1px solid yellow;
                background-color:#ff0000;
                margin:5px;
            }
            .service3{
                margin:5px;
                padding:5px;
                background-image: url(../images/);
                height:189px;
                width:90%;
                border: 1px solid yellow;
                background-color:#ff0000;
                margin:5px;
            }
            .service4{
                margin:5px;
                padding:5px;
                background-image: url(../images/);
                height:189px;
                width:90%;
                border: 1px solid yellow;
                background-color:#ff0000;
                margin:5px;
            }
            .service5{
                margin:5px;
                padding:5px;
                background-image: url(../images/);
                height:189px;
                width:90%;
                border: 1px solid yellow;
                background-color:#ff0000;
                margin:5px;
            }
            .SqlActive{
                background-color:green !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $status = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE id = 5")->fetch_object()->status; 

            // $status = 2;
        ?>
        <div class="service1 <?php echo $status >= 1 ? 'SqlActive' : ''  ?>">
            <div class="Spic">
                pic
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Shead">
                header
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Scont">
                content
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <!--service1-->
        <div class="service2 <?php echo $status >= 2 ? 'SqlActive' : ''  ?>">
            <div class="Spic">
                pic
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Shead">
                header
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Scont">
                content
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <!--service2-->
        <div class="service3 <?php echo $status >= 3 ? 'SqlActive' : ''  ?>">
            <div class="Spic">
                pic
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Shead">
                header
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Scont">
                content
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <!--service3-->
        <div class="service4 <?php echo $status >= 4 ? 'SqlActive' : ''  ?>">
            <div class="Spic">
                pic
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Shead">
                header
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Scont">
                content
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <!--service4-->
        <div class="service5 <?php echo $status >= 5 ? 'SqlActive' : ''  ?>">
            <div class="Spic">
                pic
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Shead">
                header
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="Scont">
                content
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <!--service5-->
    </body>
</html>
```